# I've got a weird problem entering formula with vlookup into a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to enter formula into cell O2 but when I do that I have #NAME? in them instead of what vlookup function should have transfered. If i manually click on formula in that cell in excel and then click enter it starts working.

```
Range("O2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,Reference_substances!B:C,2,0)"
```

Something happens when I manually "edit" formula that my macro put in that cell but I'm not actually changing anything. I don't know if it matters but sheet "Reference_substances" is created with different macro (first I run a macro that creates sheet Reference_substances and then I run macro that has vlookup in it).

Edit: Added code.

```
Sub Raport()
Dim n1 As Integer 
Dim n2 As String 
Dim n3 As String 
Dim n4 As String 
Dim n5 As String 
n1 = Worksheets("Zmienne").Range("B1")
n2 = Worksheets("Zmienne").Range("B2")
n3 = Worksheets("Zmienne").Range("B3")
n4 = Worksheets("Zmienne").Range("B4")
n5 = Worksheets("Zmienne").Range("B5")
Dim n1_1 As Integer
Dim n1_2 As Integer
Dim n1_3 As Integer
Dim n1_4 As Integer
n1_1 = n1 + 1 '121
n1_2 = n1 + 12 '132
n1_3 = n1 + 16 '136
n1_4 = n1 + 136 '256

Sheets.Add.Name = "Raport"

Worksheets(n2).Range("A12:A" & n1_2).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("A1:A" & n1_1)
Worksheets(n2).Range("B12:B" & n1_2).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("B1:B" & n1_1)
Worksheets(n2).Range("D" & n1_3 & ":D" & n1_4).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("C1:C" 
& n1_1)
Worksheets(n2).Range("G" & n1_3 & ":G" & n1_4).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("G1:G" 
& n1_1)
Worksheets(n2).Range("F12:F" & n1_2).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("H1:H" & n1_1)
Worksheets(n2).Range("C" & n1_3 & ":C" & n1_4).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("N1:N" 
& n1_1)
Worksheets(n2).Range("K13:K" & n1_2).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("Q2:Q" & n1_1)

Range("H1").Value = "Area 48h"
Range("I1").Value = "Area 48h_2"
Range("J1").Value = "Area 28d"
Range("K1").Value = "Area 28d_2"

Range("L1").Value = "C Tol 48h"
Range("M1").Value = "C Tol 28d"

Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(((RC[-4]+RC[-3])/2)/18159)/5"
Range("L2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & n1_1)

Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(((RC[-3]+RC[-2])/2)/18159)/5"
Range("M2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & n1_1)

Range("D1").Value = "C2_wz"
Range("E1").Value = "C28_wz"
Range("F1").Value = "Wzorzec"

Range("O1").Value = "a"
Range("P1").Value = "Quantific"

Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(((RC[+4]+RC[+5])/2)/RC[+11])/5"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & n1_1)
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(((RC[+5]+RC[+6])/2)/RC[+10])/5"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & n1_1)
Range("F2").Formula = "=WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO(C2,Zmienne!A:B,2,0)"
Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & n1_1)
Range("O2").Formula = "=WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO(F2,Reference_substances!B:C,2,0)"
Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O" & n1_1)

Worksheets(n2).Range("K12:K" & n1_2).Copy Worksheets("Raport").Range("Q1:Q" & n1_1)
Columns("A:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("Q:Q").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

End Sub
```

It's a bit of a mess because I just recently started with VBA and also some of the names and vlookup function are polish.

WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO is polish name for VLOOKUP (i tried with english version and it's the same)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're missing the string qualifiers around sheet name: `"=VLOOKUP(F2,'Reference_substances'!B:C,2,0)"`

Comment: @Absinthe i do not think they are needed if there are no spaces in the sheet name.

Comment: Where do you want to put this formula? In which worksheet? If you have just created the worksheet `Reference_substances`, it has become the active one. Try fully qualifying the worksheet with e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range...`.

Comment: @Absinthe adding them doesn't change anything sadly, it still works if I "edit" it

Comment: @VBasic2008 I make sure that correct worksheet is becomeing active before the code I posted. The formula is going into correct cell, it just doesn't work without editing it manually in excel.

Comment: Maybe it's a formatting issue: try `Range("O2").NumberFormat = "General"` first. BTW it's working either way on my end.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Just tried it, sadly still the same.

Comment: Maybe sharing the complete code could shed a light. Also, adding the other procedure may be of help. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67127082/edit) your post at any time. Are the worksheets in different workbooks?

Comment: @VBasic2008 added it in edit. Worksheets are in the same workbook

Comment: When adding formulas via VBA you should use the English name, not the local name, unless you use `FormulaLocal`

Comment: @TimWilliams I just tried changing it to english name and it worked this time. It didn't work before but maybe I had few problems and I fixed something else by accident and that one was my last problem. Anyway thank you very much!